# unable to update status using facebook PHP sdk: couldn't open file

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-4, facebook-php-sdk

i am trying to update Facebook status using Facebook PHP SDK. 
i have updated my status several time using the code below:

```
try {
    $session = new FacebookSession($page_token);
    $session->validate();
    (new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', '/' . $id . '/feed', array(
            'message' => $message
     )))->execute();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
   .....
}
```

but it giving me error while i am trying to update this status:

```
RiversofGrue: Returns To The Palace http://clc.li/cxG  #Grueheads #horror @crashpalace
```

surprisingly a have updated this status from  my localhost successfully. but in the production server it is throwing error.
The error is:

```
Error Message: couldn't open file "RiversofGrue: Returns To The Palace http://clc.li/cxG  #Grueheads #horror @crashpalace"
File: .../vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php
Error Code: 26
Line: 150
TraceAsString: #0 .../vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php(248): Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient->send()
#1 .../Demo.php(146): Facebook\FacebookRequest->execute()
#2 .../DemoDemo.php(31): Demo->execute()
#3 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(112): FacebookJobCommand->fire()
#4 .../vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(253): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute()
#5 .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(100): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#6 .../vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(889): Illuminate\Console\Command->run()
#7 .../vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(193): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#8 .../vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(124): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#9 .../artisan(59): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#10 {main}
```

I don't know what is the problem. Any idea guys??? 
Thanks

Comment: Show us where you define `$message`.

Comment: The message is loading from DB. i think you are thinking the message is null. OK, now think if the message is null then how the `facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php` file is able to throw exception with the message?????

Comment: No, I don't think the message is null. I do think the message might have a `@` at the beginning, which cURL thinks starts a filename to upload. Was your message originally `@RiversofGrue: Returns To The Palace...`?

Comment: YES !!!!! :O :\ the actual message is `@RiversofGrue: Returns To The Palace...`. all right, in this case what should i do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

@ceejayoz 's answer help me a lot. i was working on the wrong path. but the main problem  was `@`. if `ceejayoz` did not show me that, may be i was going to spend many more time to figure it out. if there was a way to accept two answer, i would love to accept `ceejayoz` also. thanks.

**Original:**

Finally i have decided to cut off the starting @ from the string. so i have used this:

```
if(strpos($message, "@") === 0){
    $message = substr($message, 1);
}
```

I did not find the solution, so i have used this path. if you have any other solution please post.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the message starts with `@`. cURL treats any parameter starting with `@` in a `POST` request to be a filename, and attempts to load and send that data's file contents as that parameter. This is very useful for things like file uploads, but a problem in your situation.

You should be able to fix this by wrapping your `FacebookRequest` parameters with `http_build_query` like so:

```
try {
    $session = new FacebookSession($page_token);
    $session->validate();
    (new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', '/' . $id . '/feed', http_build_query(array(
            'message' => $message
     ))))->execute();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
   .....
}
```

Comment: sorry i was on a vacation. i will give it a try. thanx :)

Comment: I have tried it. I saw that it is converting a msg like "@wow" to "%40wow". but the update on Facebook is also "%40wow", not "@wow" :( 
what should i do??